# Dell XPS 13 9350 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, 16.04

I have just received a Dell XPS 13 9350 and it is the Developer Edition with Ubuntu 14.04 preinstalled in it.

I have deleted the default Ubuntu install and I have installed Windows 10.

Now I have entered Ubuntu 16.04 LTS pendrive and when I want to install alongside with Windows 10 it doesn´t give me the option and I didn´t want to manually partition the SSD as I don´t know what to do next.

I would like to have a dual boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Note that I have also tried doing this in Legacy mode as I am working in UEFI mode now with secure boot.

I am asking for help to dual boot both OS, thank you all.

Comment: From  inside windows 10 you can use the recovery option that gives you the option to boot from UEFI USB.

Comment: 16.04 and secure boot dont like ech other atm. Had already few reports of bootloops and login problems.

Comment: I have an Asus G751JY and I didnt find any problem to dual boot. I have deleted Windows for nothing as the screen flickers on Ubuntu 16.04 because of the lack of drivers and now at the moment I am installing Windows 10 again. I will wait for intel linux graphics drivers. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) – I know you said you didn't want to do that but if the installer doesn't offer the "alongside" option then there's no way around manual partitioning in one way or another.

Comment: I gave up because doing a clean install there are no available intel drivers for 16.04 LTS